# python: itk has no attribute 'VTKImageToImageFilter'

Tags: python, coordinates, vtk, itk

In my computer, the itk has no attribute 'VTKImageToImageFilter'.

python 3.5
itk 5.0.0
win7/10

How can I convert a image from vtk to itk?

By the way, the reason why I convert a image from vtk to itk is that I want to use the TransformIndexToPhysicalPoint() function to  get the world coordinate for one pixel. More details are provided in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57130558/how-to-convert-the-coordinate-between-pixel-and-physical-vtkimagereslice).

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

That should be [working](https://discourse.itk.org/t/itk-vtkglue-for-python-3-7/1679). Did you install `itk-vtkglue` package? If yes, please submit a [bug report](https://github.com/InsightSoftwareConsortium/ITK/issues). Meanwhile, [import filter](https://itk.org/Doxygen/html/classitk_1_1ImportImageFilter.html) can be used as a workaround.